# Directional derivative of a function at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1&\mbox{if }y=x^2 \mbox{ and } x\ne 0\\ 0 &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
I want to calculate all directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$. For any $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv)}{t}.
$$
What can we say about directions of the form $(v_1, tv_1^2)$? For any different direction I see the derivative is zero, but, what about these cases? I am not pretty sure that in this case the derivative is zero. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any direction $(v_1,v_2)\not=(0,0)$, the (parametric) line $t\to (x,y)=(tv_1,tv_2)$ intersects the parabola $y=x^2$ at most at one point different from the origin (just solve $tv_2=y=x^2=(tv_1)^2$ with respect to $t$). Therefore  $f(tv_1,tv_2)$ is $0$ eventually for $t\to 0^+$ (even if $v_2=v_1^2$).

Since $f(0,0)=0$, it follows that any directional derivative is zero, as you suspected:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(tv_1,tv_2)-f(0,0)}{t}=0.$$

Comment: @DiegoVargas Any comment from your side?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: @DiegoVargas You accept and downvote at the same time!! Why?

Comment: Forgive me please, it was an error commited and I can't vote again. Please, edit the answer a little bit to give you an upvote.

Comment: @DiegoVargas OK. I edited the answer.